# How to determine timestamp field from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I got data from JSON now I want to determine whether the data is timestamp or not. But it is not a datetime object, it is string. How can I do this?

Comment: Please post some code you have tried, and some example data.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string has date, any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) to convert arbitrary timestamp-like strings to date objects.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with regex. re.match(pattern,str) function.