# How to get only date and text values from a field with Datetime and text values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

My Python field values look like below:

```
Metrics_Values
2017-12-31 00:00:00
UW Value
2017-12-31 00:00:00
2017-12-31 00:00:00
```

I want below output:

```
Metric_Values
12/31/2017
UW Value
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
```

I tried several different manipulations on this dataframe but as the values are in object datatype and as I have some text values too, I'm having trouble to get what I need.

Appreciate any pointers.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using multiple types of data within the same serie but here is a code that would do the work for you:

```
df.Metrics_Values = df.Metrics_Values.map(lambda x: x.date() if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` (which converts a string to a datetime object) and `strftime` (which converts a datetime object to a string) from `datetime` to format your dates as you wish. Here's an example:

```
import datetime as dt

def convert_format(date_string):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(date_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Then `apply` this method to your dataframe or series:

```
df.time_column.apply(lambda x: convert_format(x))
```

For the input:

```
0  2017-12-31 00:00:00
1  2017-12-31 00:00:00
```

using the above code results in:

```
0    2017/12/31
1    2017/12/31
```

See the docs on `strptime` and `strftime` for more on how they work: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thanks for your reply Henry. But this solution doesn't work for me as I've few text valued rows along with datetime rows.

Comment: @ysl in that case I'd recommend splitting up this column into separate columns or separate DataFrames. DataFrame columns should be only of one type (as Alex mentioned)

Comment: If you really must keep this format (not recommended), then you could add a line to the code I've posted where you check if the value is a date or not first. Here's how you can check if a string is in a datetime format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format . Then in this code, change `df.time_column.apply(lambda x: convert_format(x))` to `df.time_column.apply(lambda x: convert_format(x) if is_date(x) else x)`