# Check if a date is within a string in python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I am wondering how could I check if a date is within a string in Python. Imagine I have the following string:

`str = 'yesterday it was a sunny day here in Boston; I went to the park and I played with 3 dogs; 2007-03-01'`

I am trying to find a way to check if my string has a date on it but I couldn't find a way to do it, I thought of checking the numbers but that wouldn't work as I have many possibilities and numbers could be outside the date as in the string above.

What I have thought so far is to do something like:

```
str.split(';')
```

which would give me:

```
['yesterday it was a sunny day here in Boston', ' I went to the park and I played with 3 dogs', ' 2007-03-01']
```

But still I couldn't figure out a way to check if some of the elements in this new list is a date, as all of them seem to be strings. Is there any function in Python that allows to do so? Or could you give me any clue to achieve it?

I have also checked this [Check if string has date, any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format), but I am not trying to check if my string could be a date, but finding the date itself.

Comment: check the `datetime` module!

Comment: @Marisa you should re-read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945 more carefully, as it contains all you need to solve your own issue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No the link doesn't contain what the OP has asked. Read more **carefully**. OP wants to detect if a substring of a larger string is a date or note. What the other question does is, it does not check for a substring but check whether the whole string is a date or not.