# Finding data types of values from list in Python

Tags: python

I am getting a dynamic list in my code for example I have put one below and I am trying to find out the data type of each element from the list.

```
data= ['/home/sheel/Downloads/netflix_titles.csv', 'May 27, 2019', 's2804,Movie,Hope Frozen: A Quest to Live Twice,Pailin Wedel,"Jeff Ross, Bob Saget, James Adomian, Rachel Feinstein, Jerry Minor, Ayden Mayeri, Jaleel White, Natasha Leggero, Yamaneika Saunders, John Stamos, Nikki Glaser, Seth Green, Fortune Feimster, Jon Lovitz, Mindy Rickles, Gilbert Gottfried, Sasheer Zamata, Brandon T. Jackson, Ryan Phillippe, Ken Marino, Bridget Everett, John Gemberling, Leonardo Nam, Josh Homme",United States,"May 27, 2019",2019,TV-MA,1 Season,"Stand-Up Comedy & Talk Shows, TV Comedies","""Roastmaster General"" Jeff Ross and a slew of guest stars poke fun at major historical figures while also honoring their enduring impact on the world.",', None, 'TV-MA', 'Jeff Ross, Bob Saget, James Adomian, Rachel Feinstein, Jerry Minor, Ayden Mayeri, Jaleel White, Natasha Leggero, Yamaneika Saunders, John Stamos, Nikki Glaser, Seth Green, Fortune Feimster, Jon Lovitz, Mindy Rickles, Gilbert Gottfried, Sasheer Zamata, Brandon T. Jackson, Ryan Phillippe, Ken Marino, Bridget Everett, John Gemberling, Leonardo Nam, Josh Homme', 'Movie', '1', 'Stand-Up Comedy & Talk Shows, TV Comedies', '"Roastmaster General" Jeff Ross and a slew of guest stars poke fun at major historical figures while also honoring their enduring impact on the world.', 's2804', '2021-06-14T10:38:21.007Z', 'Hope Frozen: A Quest to Live Twice', 'United States', 'Pailin Wedel', '2019', '1 Season', 'sheel']
```

So far I have tried this

```
for k in data
    try:
       fieldtype.append(type(eval(str((k)))))
    except (SyntaxError,NameError,ValueError):
       fieldtype.append("string")
```

I have also tried the below functions but not working as expected.

```
isinstance()
ast.literal_eval()
```

Getting output:-

```
['string', 'string', 'string', 'None', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string']
```

Expected output:-

```
['String', 'Datetime', 'String', 'None', 'String','String','String','integer','String','String','string','DateTime','String','String','String','Datetime','String','String']
```

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question (which was closed as a duplicate), it is highly unlikely that you will be able to cast the string `May 27, 2019` back to a `datetime` without some custom checks, other than that `eval()` or `type()` should solve your problem

Comment: You can use this link solution to check string is date format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341965/10910984
And this link solution to check string is an integer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267145/10910984

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there's a problem with your data list

your expecting '2019' to be interpreted as a date, but keep in mind that '1', and literally any other integer could also be validly interpreted as dates, there is no way to distinguish between them (after all, 1 was an actual year)

as for the first Datetime, "May 27, 2019", python doesn't have any built in implementation to tell if a string represents a date, so it's just going to tell you that it's a string, if you want to be able to distinguish between strings and dates, you'll have to 1. create a class called DateTime holding a container (perhaps a list with three indexes, one for the month, one for the day, and on for the year) that represents a date, or 2. create a special function that tells you if a string represents a date, like so:

```
months = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September'\
          ,'October','November','December']
def isDateTime(x):
    try:
        items = x.split(' ')
        assert len(items) == 3
        int(items[1][0:items[1].index(',')]) # checking if day of month is an int
        int(items[2]) # checkinf if year is an int
    except (AssertionError, ValueError,AttributeError):
        return False
    return items[0] in months
```

you can then implement it in your code like so:

```
fieldtype = []

for k in data:
    try:
       if isDateTime(k):
           fieldtype.append('Datetime')
           continue
       fieldtype.append(type(eval(str((k)))))
    except (SyntaxError,NameError,ValueError):
       fieldtype.append("string")
```

the code above doesn't give exactly the expected result that you wanted (it recognizes 2019 as an int instead of a date, for the reasons stated at the top), but maybe you'll still find it useful

but ultimately, unless your in some situation where you have to recognize strings received from some external source, it would be better to just create a Datetime class specifically meant to hold dates

```
class Datetime():
    def __init__(self, month, year, day):
        self.date = [month, year, day]
```

Comment: oh wait, before I posted this, someone referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format/25341965#25341965, which is a much better solution that mine, as it can detect any formatting, while mine can only detect one specific formatting, so use that instead