# Move first date type to specific column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe, loaded from a csv, structured as well:
[image]

Who created the csv made same mistakes, and I need to move the first date which appears in each raw, to the column "Opening Date". The final result should be:

[image]

How can I do it witout specifing fom which column extract the date? (the only information I have is that it is the first one after the "Opening date" column).

Comment: please provide your data in a reproducible format (ideally as dictionary or DataFrame constructor)

Answer (score 1):

I thought a very explanatory approach.

First, we need a function that recognizes the date type. I didn't understand if there is a specific format in your csv, so when in doubt we will use a function that recognizes any pattern.

Check out '[Check if string has date, any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format)':

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date(string, fuzzy=False):
    try: 
        parse(string, fuzzy=fuzzy)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False
```

At this point, we can iterate for each row in your dataframe and where there is no value in the right column, we search on all the next ones.

```py
sub_df = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.find("Opening Data").argmax()+1:]  # retrieve only remaining columns

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row['Opening Data']:
        for col in sub_df.columns:
            if is_date(row[col]):
                df.iloc[index]['Opening Data'] = row[col]
                df.iloc[index][col] = ''
```

Starting from a dataset of this form:

|  | Opening Data | col_0 | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-01-2000 00:00:00 |  |  |
| 1 |  | 02-01-2000 00:00:00 |  |
| 2 |  |  | 03-01-2000 00:00:00 |

the output will be:

|  | Opening Data | col_0 | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-01-2000 00:00:00 |  |  |
| 1 | 02-01-2000 00:00:00 |  |  |
| 2 | 03-01-2000 00:00:00 |  |  |